# How are shortcuts added to Androids widget menu?

Tags: java, android, widget, shortcut

I know how to add a [widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264809/how-to-build-a-simple-android-widget) and [shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151724/creating-a-shortcut-of-an-android-application-on-home-screen) in general, but haven't been able to figure out how some apps like Google Maps add shortcuts to the *launcher's widget menu*.  I've been researching it for days with no luck.

I know these are not ordinary 1x1 widgets, because I cannot resize them, and they can be put in folders like normal apps (which is not possible with small widgets), plus, Nova Launcher shows them with a word "shortcut".

Comment: I'm not an Android programmer, but I found  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977934/how-to-programmatically-create-a-shortcut-of-another-app-in-android) and  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26847824/android-adding-widgets-to-app-programmatically-warning-message). Do either of those help?

Comment: They're essentially the same as your "shortcuts" link, but they don't require a permission as the user adds them via the launcher rather than the app adding them to the launcher. I posted details at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41592723/android-define-shortcut-that-can-be-used-in-custom-launcher

Comment: Do you refer to the ones [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41688735/5193581)?