# Shortcuts vs Launcher Widgets (Android)

Tags: android, shortcut, launcher, android-launcher

We have enabled shortcuts for two of our app screen. Using manifest, we have initialized Activity which is referring to the shortcut as below.

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.shortcuts.ShortCut1"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:icon="@drawable/shortcut1"
    android:label="@string/app_shortcut_name1"
    android:theme="@style/AppLightTheme">
       <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />
       </intent-filter>

 </activity>
```

From code I have enabled the shortcuts as follows.

```
Intent shortcutIntent = null;
shortcutIntent = new Intent(ApplicationNekt.getContext(), ShortCut1.class);

shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);



intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, ApplicationNekt.getContext().getString(R.string.app_shortcut_name1));
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(ApplicationNekt.getContext(), R.drawable.shortcut1));

intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
ApplicationNekt.getContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Now In Nova and Action launchers, they display the shortcuts under shortcuts section with the icon and text i gave in manifest. If I click and hold , I am able to place the icon on home tab. Immediately after that, my target activity opens. But the when I go back to phone home screen, shortcut icon they created in previous step was removed.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kevin from Nova launcher replied to support email.

Its also explained in different thread [Android define shortcut that can be used in custom launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41592723/android-define-shortcut-that-can-be-used-in-custom-launcher/41688735#41688735)

In my case, I have both shortcut adding code as well as I want to support users who wants to add shortcuts from Nova/Action Launcher's Widget screen. So I did the following.

Below code I wrote in ShortCut1.java class file. This is the activity code.

```
public class ShortCut1 extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // This code runs when the user actually clicks and 
    // opens the shortcut. so redirect him to target screen.  
    openTargetTab(0);


    // This code is useful when called by the Nova/Action launcher's 
    // widget is clicked. So return them with icon, name and target 
    // activity. Once they receive it they will set the short cut icon on home. 
    // Note: Even when the shortcut is clicked, this result is set, 
    //   but nobody reads the response. So it should be ok. 
    Intent resIntent = getResIntent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK, resIntent);

    finish();
}

private Intent getResIntent() {

    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent();
    // Target intent is set to this own class. So that when the user clicks on the shortcut this intent will be passed.
    Intent target = new Intent(this, ShortCut1.class);
    shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, target);
    shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, 
         Application.getContext().getString(R.string.shortcut_name));
    shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
        Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(Application.getContext(), 
                                                R.drawable.shortcut1));
    return shortcutIntent;
}

private void openHomeTab(int tabIndex) {

    // Final target screen. 
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

NOTE: I have not removed or changed any code on Manifest or the shortcut adding code. As I need that support also in my app, I left that code as it is. So when the user clicks on "Add shortcut", that code will run. Only change I did here is, I have called "Setresult" with proper intent which is understandable by 3rd party launchers.